# Тректория движения пули в 2D

Tags: c#, monogame

Есть такое решение для стрельбы как в enter the gungeon(пулька летит в сторону курсора мышки):

```cs
            if (mouseState.LeftButton.Equals(ButtonState.Pressed) && oldMouseState.LeftButton.Equals(ButtonState.Released))
            {
                Vector2 destinantion = mouseState.Position.ToVector2() - position;
                Vector2 speed = new Vector2(3, 3 * destinantion.Y / destinantion.X);
                speed.Normalize();
                //float x = 3 * (float)Math.Sqrt(destinantion.X * destinantion.X + destinantion.Y * destinantion.Y) / destinantion.Y;
                bullets.Add(new Bullet(bulletTexture, position, speed * 6));
            }
```

destination - расстояние от курсора мышки от игрока
speed - через тангенс высчитываю куда сдвигать пульку каждый тик
Дальше это все нормализуется и добавляется в пульку.
Но работает все это пока destination не отрицательный, если мышка по координатам левее игрока пульки летят в противоположную сторону(там все равно положительное число выходит).
Есть ли более красивое решение такого или можно ли как-то пофиксить это сейчас?

Comment: У меня для Вас хорошая новость. Вектор destination уже направлен на курсор.

Comment: Так мне полет нужен плавный, тут и считается насколько сдвигать каждый тик чтобы летело именно туда.

Comment: Ну так Вы не путайте направление и длину вектора. Вы лишними расчетами меняете его направление. Вектор destination направлен к курсору, скопируйте его в speed, нормализуйте, умножьте на коэффициент. Вы же описываете проблему не плавности, а направления